# fb:swf is coming up white after image click

Tags: flash, facebook

Hi hope someone can explain what is wrong with this code as the files work fine.

the image loads then i click it and guess what i get a white screen I've been trying loads of forums and stuff can someone point out for what reason this can be happening.

```
<fb:swf 
 swfsrc='http://www.magro.com.mt/savinafacebookfanpage/dock_purchased/DockGallery.swf' 
 imgsrc='http://www.magro.com.mt/savinafacebookfanpage/dock_purchased/01.gif' 
 width='495' height='360' />
```

Comment: sorry about that didn't notice that code wasn't there

Comment: just so that if anyone comments i removed one directory dock_purchased since i don't need it

Answer (score 0):

Have you solved this? The problem that jumps out at me is that both the SWF and the image are not found (404). You probably moved the files since you posted this, but just in case...